# Event stops working after another event

Tags: meteor

I have a textbox with event that stores textbox's value in session and displays this value on page. And i have a list of images with event that adds a image url to the textbox after clicking on image. But it's stops working("adding images" event) if some text are writen in a textbox manually.

Here's the code:

```
<template name="imgList">   
    <div style="width: 500px; height: 100px; overflow: auto;">
        {{#each images}}
            ||<img src="{{this.url}}" class="pic">
        {{/each}}
    </div>
    <textarea class="tbox" cols="50" rows="20"></textarea><br />
    {{#markdown}}{{text}}{{/markdown}}
</template>



Template.imgList.helpers
    images: -> 
        Meteor.Images.find {}, sort: 
            uploadedAt: -1 
    text: ->
        Session.get('text')

Template.imgList.events 
    'keyup .tbox': (evt, temp) ->
        Session.set('text', $('.tbox').val())
    'click .pic': (evt, temp) -> 
        img = evt.target.src
        $(".tbox").append(img)
```

Comment: Is it possible that some exception is thrown and it blocks the code from further execution? Do you see any logs in the console?

Comment: No any errors on both server and client.